# Could quantum computers answer the question of whether QCD predicts quark gluon confinement?

Tags: complexity-theory, simulation, speedup

As I understand it, it is not known whether or not QCD actually predicts quark gluon confinement.

As I understand it answering questions in quantum field theories is generally harder in terms of computation than answering questions in quantum mechanics.  I understand that in Quantum Mechanics there is one wavefunction for a system of particles, which is a function of the possible position of each particle, which makes it sound like the computational time needed to simulate a wavefunction of multiple particles would in general go up exponentially with the number of particles.  From this I might suspect that the question on whether or not QCD predicts quark gluon confinement is at least at the difficulty of being an EXPTime problem, if not harder, and I understand that the types of problems that quantum computers tend to be able to solve are ones that are NP problems.

So my question is could a quantum computer answer the question on whether or not QCD predicts quark gluon confinement, or is this question too hard even for a quantum computer?

Comment: Your comments in the second paragraph about complexity classes are a little awkward.  But +1 for the main question. What is the background for why quark-gluon confinement is hard to predict?